# Wordpress. Как вывести отдельные типы записей и таксономии + слайдер

Tags: wordpress

Не смог разобраться с выводом отдельного типа записи и таксономии
Есть отдельный тип записей "estate" и таксономия "Рекомендуемые"(которая распространяется почти на все типы записей) recom и хочу вывести из термина recomend

Есть к нему слайдер

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="item">
            <ul id="content-slider" class="content-slider">

                <li>
                    <h3>1</h3>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3>2</h3>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3>3</h3>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3>4</h3>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3>5</h3>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3>6</h3>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать нормальный вывод из типа estate и таксономии Рекомендуемые?

Делал так:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="item">
            <ul id="content-slider" class="content-slider">
         <?php 
   $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'estate',
'taxonomy' => 'recomend',
    'posts_per_page' => 12
    )); 
   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
   $the_query->the_post();
  ?>    
                <li>
                     <?php the_post_thumbnail('lg');?>
                </li>
  <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Но как итог выводится только все записи, а не из рекомендуемых

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил всё таким путём

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="item">
            <ul id="content-slider" class="content-slider">
<?php
   $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'estate',
      'tax_query' => array(
         array(
            'taxonomy' => 'recom',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'recomend'
         )
      )
   );
   $estate = new WP_Query( $args );
   if( $estate->have_posts() ) {
      while( $estate->have_posts() ) {
         $estate->the_post();
         ?>
                <li>
                     <?php the_post_thumbnail('lg');?>
                </li>
         <?php
      }
   }
   else {
      echo 'На данный момент нету рекомендуемых';
   }
?>

            </ul>
        </div>
```